How can I copy Chrome extension IDs or names from Chrome's Task Manager?
Example:

I want to know which Chrome extension is clogging the CPU.
I don't want to type eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh myself, I'd like to copy it instead. I use Windows 10. How can I copy the extension ID or name from Chrome's Task Manager?

Though I know of no eway to do that in Chrome itself, you might try a third-party app such as Nirsoft's BrowserAddonsView or an alternative, which shows details about each extension for all browsers - whether Chrome-based (e.g., Chrome, Edge), Firefox-based (Firefox, Tor Browser) or other.

BrowserAddonsView shows details of each extension and lets you copy the encrypted "name" (Item ID) and other data. You can save all the information to a text file, too. However, it cannot disable or enable add-ons, though, perhaps because that might be considered a security issue.
BTW, I was greatly surprised at the great number of extensions installed by the browser itself, and BrowserAddonsView alerted me to a few in Edge I consider obnoxious.

Works great, thanks!

BTW, Google Chrome browser will no longer support many extensions in framework v. 3, such as uBlock Origin: https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/browsing/google-pulls-the-plug-on-ublock-origin , so check that add-on list again after Chrome and Edge updates. [Firefox and other browsers not based on Chrome still support it.]
